# Difficult arithmetic trying to follow textbook in probability

Tags: probability

Struggling with some steps from my textbook:

This is what i have been given:

> $s(1)=0$ , s(0)=1 and $s(s(x))=x$ (in other words a self-reciprocal function)

$$x s\left(\frac{s(y)}{x}\right)=y s\left(\frac{s(x)}{y}\right)$$

where

$$\frac{s(x)}{y}=1-e^{-q}$$

and $$s\left(1-e^{-q}\right) =e^{-j(q)}$$

This information is supposed to help me solve for s(y);
Now q here is initially a function of x and y, and we shall consider x and q as the independent variables.

Now solving for s(y) the answer is:

> $$s(y)=O(\exp (-2 q))+\exp (-q) s(x) s'(s(x))+s(s(x))$$

I have tried up down for hours and hours, actually days:(  and I am at the point where If I do not get it soon I give up and put my textbook away.

Comment: what is the textbook?

Comment: Probability Theory: The logic of Science

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Begin with 
$$S(y) = S \bigg[\frac{S(x)}{1-e^{-q}} \bigg] $$

then use taylor $f(x+h) = f(x) + f'(x)h + O(h^2)$

Therefore
$$S(y) = S(S(x)) + S'(S(x)) \bigg[\frac{S(x)}{1-e^{-q}} - S(X)\bigg]  + O(\bigg[\frac{S(x)}{1-e^{-q}} - S(X)\bigg]^2)$$

since $x$ is held fixed $$O(\bigg[\frac{S(x)}{1-e^{-q}} - S(X)\bigg]^2) = O\bigg(\bigg[\frac{1}{1-e^{-q}} - 1\bigg]^2\bigg) =O\bigg(\bigg[\frac{e^{-q}}{1-e^{-q}}\bigg]^2\bigg)  = O(e^{-2q})$$

moreover
$$\bigg[\frac{S(x)}{1-e^{-q}} - S(X)\bigg] = S(x) \frac{e^{-q}}{1- e^{-q}} =S(x) e^{-q} + S(x) \frac{e^{-q}}{1- e^{-q}} -S(x) e^{-q} = S(x)e^{-q} + S(X) \frac{e^{-2q}}{1 - e^{-q}}  = S(x)e^{-q} + O(e^{-2q})  $$

**Note:** Since $e^{-q} \leq \frac{S(x)}{y} + 1$ and $x,y \in [0,1]$  we can indeed say that

$$O\bigg(\bigg[\frac{e^{-q}}{1-e^{-q}}\bigg]^2\bigg)  = O(e^{-2q}) $$

Comment: Oh, Thank you soooooooo much! I think maybe my textbook is too difficult at the moment. Do you know any good books where I can learn to analyse functions like this, f. eks how did you realise your: NOTE

Comment: :) I am glad. This textbook is very surprising since it deals with logic and probability. It requires knowledge that often are not develloped together I couldn't know an equivalent textbook. What do you mean by eks?

Comment: The NOTE comes from the fact that if $e^{-q}$ is bounded then $$O\bigg(\bigg[\frac{e^{-q}}{1-e^{-q}}\bigg]^2\bigg)  = O(e^{-2q})$$ however even when $e^{-q}$ is large it is still true that $$O\bigg(\bigg[\frac{e^{-q}}{1-e^{-q}}\bigg]^2\bigg)  = O(e^{-2q}) $$ So the note is not very interesting

Comment: ups Norwegian abbreviation. function in this example

Comment: I dont have a teacher and I am studying maths by myself. I am interesting in learning to do analysis of functions like you have done now and  obviously you have a deep understanding, which textbooks do you recommend me to work my way through so that I am able to realise stuff like this.

Comment: I don't need it to be on probability.

Comment: I am Brazilian, so The books I can indicate to you are in Portuguese which might be of little help. I suggest you take a look at an introductory book in real analysis, I like Walter Rudin's book  but there are a lot of good books in the subject. Should you have any further question I encourage you to ask it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27242/discussion-between-alexander-and-conrado-costa).